# Change the order of directives based on values returned from server

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, components, directive

Imagine I have three components: `componentA`,`componentB`,`componentC`, and these components are used in my main page, on page load I receive the order of these components like so:

```
{
    "componentA": 3,
    "componentC": 2,
    "componentB": 1
}
```

How can I place these directives in order returned by server in my main page:

```
<div class="container">
   <componentB></componentB>
   <componentC></componentC>
   <componentA></componentA>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can created an array of the Keys sorted:

```
var list = {
  "componentA": 3,
  "componentC": 2,
  "componentB": 1
}

var listSorted = Object.keys(list).sort(function(a,b){return list[a]-list[b]})
console.log(listSorted) // ["componentB", "componentC", "componentA"]
```

Then you can use ng-switch (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)
Whilst using ng-repeat (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to iterative over the array.  Allowing you to writeconditions on each component to determine to render it.

```
<div ng-repeat="componentName in $ctrl.listSorted track by $index"
ng-switch="componentName">
  <componentA ng-switch-when="componentA">...</componentA>
  <componentB ng-switch-when="componentB">...</componentB>
  <componentC ng-switch-when="componentC">...</componentC>
</div>
```

Comment: using `ng-switch` dosen't cause trouble with scopes? imagine `componentA` needs `listA` which is in parent controller, is it accessible from inside of `ng-switch`?

Comment: Are you passing `listA` as a binding into ComponentA?  That would still work